# Replace all observations except for the first with 0 in each ID

Tags: r, replace, data.table, panel-data

I have a dataset that looks something like this.

```
    ID    date   price   day 
    a     2005/5   100    16
    a     2005/6   110    1
    a     2005/7   90     1
    b     2005/5   90     20 
    b     2005/6   100    1
    b     2005/7   90     1  
    c     2005/5   90     3 
    c     2005/6   95     1
    c     2005/7   100    1
```

And for the day column, I want to replace every row EXCEPT the first row into 0. 
So my desired result is as below.

```
    ID    date   price   day 
    a     2005/5   100    16
    a     2005/6   110    0
    a     2005/7   90     0
    b     2005/5   90     20 
    b     2005/6   100    0
    b     2005/7   90     0  
    c     2005/5   90     3 
    c     2005/6   95     0
    c     2005/7   100    0
```

I have tried using command such as

```
    rbonds1 <- as.data.table(rbonds1)
    setkey(rbonds1,ID,date)
    rbonds1[rbonds1[-1, 21]==0,by=ID]
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by replacing `day` with 0 whenever `ID` is duplicated:

```
rbonds1$day[duplicated(rbonds1$ID)] <- 0
rbonds1
#   ID   date price day
# 1  a 2005/5   100  16
# 2  a 2005/6   110   0
# 3  a 2005/7    90   0
# 4  b 2005/5    90  20
# 5  b 2005/6   100   0
# 6  b 2005/7    90   0
# 7  c 2005/5    90   3
# 8  c 2005/6    95   0
# 9  c 2005/7   100   0
```

Comment: @josliber I have a quick another question. Can I do `rbonds1$day[duplicated(rbonds1$ID)] <- rbonds1$day[!duplicated(rbonds1$ID)]` if I want to replace all the other variables as the value in the first row in each ID?

Comment: @hk824 So you want to replace all the values in day by first value of day from each group ID ?

Comment: @hk824 You could try: `library(dplyr); rbonds1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(day = first(day))`

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table` (as the OP showed some attempts in `data.table`).  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we get the row index (`.I`) where the sequence is not 1, extract that column ('V1') and assign (`:=`) the 'day' to 0 for those rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[,.I[1:.N!=1] , by = ID]$V1, day:=0][]
#   ID   date price day
#1:  a 2005/5   100  16
#2:  a 2005/6   110   0
#3:  a 2005/7    90   0
#4:  b 2005/5    90  20
#5:  b 2005/6   100   0
#6:  b 2005/7    90   0
#7:  c 2005/5    90   3
#8:  c 2005/6    95   0
#9:  c 2005/7   100   0
```